# Почему Json не передается в контроллер?? C# Asp.Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, json, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

Код контроллера (к примеру):

```
public async Task<string> Login(LoginModel model)
{
    return model.Email;
}
```

Код LoginModel:

```
public class LoginModel
{
    [JsonPropertyName("Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Отправляю вот так:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44345");
HttpContent hs = new StringContent("{\"Email\":\"mail@mail.ru\",\"Password\":\"password\"} ", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = client.PostAsync("Auth/Login", hs).Result;
```

В ответ получаю то, что вместо данных в Json попадают Null. Думал на счет того, чтобы передавать в `void Login(string json)`, но тогда мне получается нужно будет отправлять Key "json" Value "Сам json", чего мне не хотелось бы делать... Или я что-то не так понимаю или дико с чем-то туплю.

Использовать x-www-form-urlencoded я умею, но мне нужно именно json.

Comment: Попробуйте в хидер запроса доабвить Content-Type=application/json

Comment: + я бы добавил перед аргументом [FromBody], хотя не уверне, что это решает

Comment: `model.Login` - ??

Comment: ошибочка с model.Login)) model.Email. Но в основном коде у меня все правильно было.

Comment: Как раз таки добавил [FromBody] и все решилось)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня есть проект созданный из совершенно типового шаблонного проекта webapi (тот где по умолчанию подставляется ValueController, думаю видели), я на нём много экспериментировал с биндингами.

Вот полный пример.

Так должен выглядеть код контроллера:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AsdfController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<string> Method([FromBody] Request request)
        {
            return $"post, value1={request.Value1}, value2={request.Value2}.";
        }
    }

    public class Request
    {
        public int Value1 { get; set; }

        public string Value2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Вот так код клиента в linqpad:

```
void Main()
{
    var unit = new WebRequestHelper();

    // Post samples as json

    unit.PostAsync("https://localhost:44323/api/asdf", "{\"Value1\":5,\"Value2\":\"asdf\"}")
        .Result.Dump(); // Expected: post, value1=5, value2=asdf.

    unit.PostAsync("https://localhost:44323/api/asdf", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Value1 = 1, Value2 = "asdf", }))
        .Result.Dump(); // Expected: post, value1=5, value2=asdf.
        
    // Free for your samples
}
```

И сам хелпер:

```
public class WebRequestHelper
{
    public async Task<string> PostAsync(string uri, string jsonString)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");     
        var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Пробуйте, вам в комментариях всё верно отписали, осталось только сложить аккуратно всё воедино. Модель свою подставите вместо анонимной, там просто обычный класс с геттерами и сеттерами. Можете даже убрать атрибуты `JsonPropertyName` они в вашем случае избыточны, т.к. конвенциональны.

Comment: А зачем нужен [ApiController] ? Я его не использовал у себя, хоть у меня и практически тоже самое должно выполнять приложение (тоже WebApi)

Comment: @VillyFiki Это проект asp.net core 2.1, ЕМНИП там что-то не заводилось в роутере, если не указывать атрибут.